# Spring JPA: Parameter 0 of constructor in ... required a bean of type ... that could not be found

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I do a simple web app but on start I get that error. I'm using `Spring JPA`.  The message's about Spring could not find any bean to do `autowired`. But if I use `CrudRepository` I always have standard repository implementation. I can't get why Spring can't find own bean? What do I do wrong?

**Service layer**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/get")
public class UserService {
    private final UserRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public UserService(UserRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }
```

**Repository**

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add annotation `@Repository` - it will allow Spring to discover this repository during Component Scan

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

Comment: no, it's not. It's interface and not implementation. There's nothing to autowired. But Spring base impl already has annotation @Repository.

Answer (score 0):

I get it: I forgot to add default constructor for my model class. And if I use this class in Spring jpa `CrudRepository<User, Long>` it has to be with some default constructor.